# How to start mysql service without systemctl/service tool

Tags: mysql, centos

Mysql service is running on centos system. Recently we had a planned power outage so we shut down the mysql services.
I am bringing back the service now. I wish to run mysqld_safe as mysql user and not to start as root and not to use systemctl/service.

The only method I know is:

sudo systemctl mysql restart

sudo service mysql start

Anyone have any inputs on how I can start mysql service as mysql user without using systemctl/service tool.

I tried this in /usr/bin
 `mysqld_safe -user=mysql &` and got permission denied error

Thanks for you inputs in advance.

Comment: Your manager is incompetent. systemctl/init script correctly call setuid to mysql user. Anyway, voting to move question to SF.